# Quadrature formula

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

How can we find a quadrature formula $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx=c \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{2}f(x_i)$ that is exact for all quadratic polynomials?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\ dx =\int_{-1}^{1} ax^2+bx+c\ dx =\frac{2a}{3}+2c$$
Moreover you want to have three points all having the same weights. To make life simpler, let's also assume symmetry:

$$w\left(f(-x_0)+f(0)+f(x_0)\right) =\frac{2a}{3}+2c$$
$$w\left(2ax_0^2+3c\right)=\frac{2a}{3}+2c$$
It's clear that $w$ must be $2/3$, and so:
$$x_0^2 = 1/2 \to x_0=1/\sqrt{2}$$
All in all you have:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\ dx \sim \frac{2}{3}\left(f(-1/\sqrt{2})+f(0)+f(1/\sqrt{2}) \right)$$

**Edit:** You can of course choose *any* three points and still get exact results, but this makes the calculation far less elegant.

Comment: Thanks! It's well explained!

Comment: Strange... you could pick _any_ 3 points, interpolate Lagrange and integrate the result. It will be exact for _all_ quadratic polynomials, I see no way this could fix your $x_0$.

Comment: @vonbrand - it wouldn't fix $x_0$.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Simpson's rule has non-equal weights. Brain slippage.

Comment: @nbubis Can you add more detail to your answer? I don't understand how you got $x_0^2-1/2$

Comment: @UsernameUnknown if you know $w=2/3$, than once you compare the coefficients for $a$ you get the desired relationship.

Comment: @nbubis I'm sorry but I still don't see how you were able to determine that the quadratic equation is the one you state

Comment: @UsernameUnknown To spell it out: $ (2/3)(2ax_0^2) = (4/3)a x_0^2 = 2a/3$. Multiply by three, divide by $2a$,  and you get $2 x_0^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

For a quadratic function, you can find an exact representation from any three samples $x_i$.  Thus, determine coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$ of $y=a x^2+b x+c$ from these samples, and then integrate $y$ between $[-1,1]$.